# Transformer for cabinet lights 2W 12VAC 175mA

Tags: led

I am replacing some incandescent bulbs with LED in a dimmable 3 light array above a kitchen sink (high enough to not be at risk of moisture).

The 3 LED bulbs are each 2W 175mA 12VAC 60hz. I cannot find a transformer to step down to 12VAC around 15-20W, plenty of DC though. Is it ok to use DC or should I be looking for a different (DC) bulb? Can someone share an example of a dimmable 12v transformer/specs I should be considering.

Comment: door bell transformers, HVAC transformers are all AC

Comment: *"I cannot find a transformer"* Look harder, they're commonplace. First place I looked had 200 different models.. You cannot substitute DC for AC. Search "power supply" not "transformer". A power supply contains a transformer, but a transformer is not necessarily a power supply itself.

Comment: @tetsujin thank you for your unhelpful remark, that’s not what I said. What I actually said was “I cannot find a transformer to step down *to 12VAC around 15-20W*”

Comment: Then you're still not looking in the right place. As to "unhelpful" I gave you a search term, I can't type it out for you in your browser. I said don't search "transformer" because that's not what you need, or more specifically, that's not how it might be described. Search "power supply" or actually just search "12v ac 20w". Even limited to that requirement I still have 30 to choose from, all on one site… but it's no use me telling you the site, I'm UK, so it's all 240v 50Hz.